# multiple requests accessing the same web method

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, request

It is a very basic question. When two requests access the same method of a singleton object , how is it handled. Does tomcat(or any other container) create a ThreadLocal instance for every object ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by web method you mean a method in your code that a servlet container like tomcat's catalina would map a HTTP request to. Tomcat tries to service each request in its own thread and I would assume these threads would eventually get run on the sole instance of the singleton object that has the web method. The maxThreads attribute in server.xml can set a limit on how many such threads would get spawned at a time.

Comment: My question is , when two requests (threads) access the same method , how is synchronization done ?